# 0x00000e9 error on boot Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Recently when booting up my computer, the OS (Windows 10 Pro 64-bit) failed to load. When booting off of my primary drive, I received the following error:

> 0xc000000e A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed.
>   You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation
>   media (like a disk or USB device), contact your PC administrator or
>   PC/Device manufacturer

When booting off of the secondary, I receive a different error:

> 0x00000e9 An unexpected I/O error has occurred. This problem can
>   happen when a removable storage is removed while it's in use or is
>   failing. Properly connecting any removable storage and restarting your
>   PC may fix this problem

I suspect that the primary drive is fine, and that the secondary drive is the problem. While the OS is installed to the primary drive, it used to be installed on the secondary drive before I did a clean install of Windows. I believe the MBR is still on the secondary drive, which would explain why the primary can't boot on its own. This is further reinforced by the secondary drive being the first in the load order between the two.

I installed Windows on a small (40 GB!) drive so I could boot into Windows and check on the status of the other two (Primary is 1 TB from 2012; Secondary is 0.5 TB from 2009). Pictured below is a screenshot from Disk Management run through the Windows I installed on the recovery drive. Disk 0 = recovery, Disk 1 = primary, and Disk 2 = Secondary:

[image]

All partitions (which aren't connected via RAID/etc) are showing up as healthy, and from Windows on the recovery drive I'm able to access the contents of the other drives no problem. Because the partitions are healthy, I'm unsure if this is an issue of wear and tear or the MBR somehow being damaged through other means. The PC was last rebooted by AMD's Radeon Crimson driver installer after it updated drivers, so it's not like it was abruptly shut down.

If possible, I would prefer to keep the contents of both drives, as well as the configurations to the Windows install. When I try to repair the OS install via USB, I'm told to boot from the damaged drive and repair from there, but this is impossible as booting from that drive immediately errors. How can I repair the drive(s) without losing my data, and potentially move the MBR to my primary drive? Should I look into replacing the secondary and/or primary drive as well?

Edit:
Using the Windows installation USB, I opened the recovery command prompt and through using `bootrec /scanos` Windows was found on my primary drive. I then ran `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`, and restarted the computer. It was to no avail though as I'm still receiving the same error.

Edit:
I tried using `bootrec /rebuildbcd` and while booting from primary gives the same error, now I'm also getting the following error when I boot into repair from the recovery USB:

> The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors. File:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD Error code: 0xc000000f

Edit: Fixed 0xc000000f error by re-creating the bootable USB. Concerning that it was damaged instead of my drive -- was `/rebuild bcd` targeting the USB instead of the drive?