# My drive has the active flag, but not boot -- is it necessary?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I installed Windows to a new drive to help repair my broken drive(s), but I noticed something odd:

[image]

The new drive (Disk 0) has the Active and System flags enabled, and its Boot is on the data partition, C:. Disk 1, where Windows is installed to on my old drives, has the Active flag on the data partition, and is missing all other flags Disk 0 has. Disk 2 has a System Reserved partition which has the active flag enabled, but is missing the system flag and its data partition doesn't have the boot / etc flags like Disk 0 does.

Should Disk 1 and Disk 2 have the same flags as Disk 0 -- and not having them is related to them not working -- or are those flags not entirely necessary, and Disk 1 and Disk 2 have the appropriate flags / partitions needed to boot?

Comment: @Ramhound Disk 1 and Disk 2 aren't booting -- I'm trying to discern the cause by looking at the flags. Both Disk0 and Disk1 were clean installed with Windows 10 (though Windows was installed on Disk1 months back), so I would think they would have similar flags.

Comment: Perhaps these flags are not stored but computed during boot. I have 2 HDDs containing near identical data. Both HDDs can be booted from but right now, only one has the boot flag which happens to be the HDD I booted from.

Comment: @Ramhound `bootrec /scanos` shows Windows installs on Disk0's C partition and Disk1's E partition. Not sure if that's what you meant by BCD

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry -- didn't want to go off scope of the original question. I have [another question up](https://superuser.com/questions/1195818/0x00000e9-error-on-boot-windows-10) which provides a lot of detail of the issue, but it hasn't attracted any comments/etc -- I imagine because its scope is so large -- so I've been trying to progress further so that I can simplify the problem.

Comment: Drew, it is better to edit a question than to create a new one. Also, that other question hadn't been up very long before you opened this one. I'd suggest rewording the title to be more direct, and leaving the errors and technical details for the body just as a simple way to make the question more likely to get attention and answers.

Comment: @music2myear This isn't a simplification of the first question -- it's part of the overall first question. Say I did edit it -- after Fleet answered this one, should I edit the already-answered question to ask the next part of the first question, or make a new one? I wouldn't think combining them would be appropriate.

Comment: Then probably delete the other one. There are some downsides to deleting as a low-rep user, but so long as you don't do it too many times it shouldn't hurt at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, a very observant question. Unfortunately, you **have fallen into the trap of Microsoft's fangled terminology**.

Hold on to your pants for a big surprise, because here is how Microsoft defines "Boot" and "System" partitions:

- A "Boot" partition is NOT the partition on which boot files (bootloader) reside! It is the partition on which the system root (%systemroot%) resides!
- A "System" partition is NOT the partition on which the system root (%systemroot%) resides! It is the partition on which the boot files (bootloader) reside!

If you ever discovered why the hell Microsoft has assigned the wrong the definition to the wrong term, let me know too. Also see: [System partition and boot partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=System_partition_and_boot_partition&oldid=774127706) on English Wikipedia

Now, about the "Active" flag: BIOS or UEFI look for boot files on the partition that is marked as active. Only one partition at a time can be marked as active. Hence, it only makes sense to mark your "System" partition as active.

I am sure you have concluded by now, but I am going to say it anyway: "Boot" and "System" are not actual flags. They are just labels that only appear in Disk Management console. But "Active" is an actual flag; there is a certain area of disk for holding this flag as information. **None of your partitions on Disk 2 have these labels** because they are neither used to boot Windows nor contain the copy of Windows that is running. There maybe bootloader files in F: and a working Windows on G:, but Disk Management console does not check and does not care.

Comment: Nice write up... again with some style... +1... I like your explanation since it sounds fun!!